# ValueError: could not convert string to float: balance = float(clean)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python3 in a bot on Telegram, but I'm encountering an error when trying to execute some commands.
The bot is a cryptocurrency wallet, and this bot is connected to a wallet that is running on the same server where the bot is hosted.
The connection is made via RPC commands.
Error follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 343, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 122, in handle_update
    return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
  File "command.py", line 86, in funds
    balance  = float(clean)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

[image]

This would be my code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import codecs
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re
import subprocess
from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async
from telegram.ext import Updater
from html import escape

updater = Updater(token='TOKEN_TELEGRAM')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='log.log',
                    filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)

def commands(bot, update):
    user = update.message.from_user.username
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=" List of commands: \n "+
        " /hello \n /commands \n /recharge \n /pay \n /drawout \n /funds \n /price \n /help")

def help(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=" /pay & /drawout have a specfic format use them like so:"+
        "\n Parameters: \n <user> = target user to pay \n <amount> = amount of SperoCoin to utilise \n <address> = SperoCoin address to withdraw to \n \n Tipping format: \n /pay <user> <amount> \n \n Withdrawing format: \n /drawout <address> <amount>")

def recharge(bot, update):
    user = update.message.from_user.username
    if user is None:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Please set a telegram username in your profile settings!")
    else:
        address = "/usr/local/bin/SperoCoind"
        extra1 = "-datadir=/coin/data"
        extra2 = "-conf=/coin/sperocoin.conf"
        result = subprocess.run([address,extra1,extra2,"getaccountaddress",user],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        clean = (result.stdout.strip()).decode("utf-8")
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="@{0} your depositing address is: {1}".format(user,clean))

def pay(bot,update):
    user = update.message.from_user.username
    target = update.message.text[5:]
    amount =  target.split(" ")[1]
    target =  target.split(" ")[0]
    if user is None:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Please set a telegram username in your profile settings!")
    else:
        machine = "@SperoCoinWalletBot"
        if target == machine:
            bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="HODL.")
        elif "@" in target:
            target = target[1:]
            user = update.message.from_user.username
            core = "/usr/local/bin/SperoCoind"
            extra1 = "-datadir=/coin/data"
            extra2 = "-conf=/coin/sperocoin.conf"
            result = subprocess.run([core,extra1,extra2,"getbalance",user],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            balance = float((result.stdout.strip()).decode("utf-8"))
            amount = float(amount)
            if balance < amount:
                bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="@{0} you have insufficent funds.".format(user))
            elif target == user:
                bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="You can't pay yourself!")
            else:
                balance = str(balance)
                amount = str(amount)
                tx = subprocess.run([core,extra1,extra2,"move",user,target,amount],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="@{0} paid @{1} of {2} SPERO".format(user, target, amount))
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Error that user is not applicable.")

def funds(bot,update):
    user = update.message.from_user.username
    if user is None:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Please set a telegram username in your profile settings!")
    else:
        core = "/usr/local/bin/SperoCoind"
        extra1 = "-datadir=/coin/data"
        extra2 = "-conf=/coin/sperocoin.conf"
        result = subprocess.run([core,extra1,extra2,"getbalance",user],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        clean = (result.stdout.strip()).decode("utf-8")
        balance  = float(clean)
        balance =  str(round(balance,3))
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="@{0} your current balance is: {1} SPERO ".format(user,balance))



def drawout(bot,update):
    user = update.message.from_user.username
    if user is None:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Please set a telegram username in your profile settings!")
    else:
        target = update.message.text[9:]
        address = target[:35]
        address = ''.join(str(e) for e in address)
        target = target.replace(target[:35], '')
        amount = float(target)
        core = "/usr/local/bin/SperoCoind"
        extra1 = "-datadir=/coin/data"
        extra2 = "-conf=/coin/sperocoin.conf"
        result = subprocess.run([core,extra1,extra2,"getbalance",user],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        clean = (result.stdout.strip()).decode("utf-8")
        balance = float(clean)
        if balance < amount:
            bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="@{0} you have insufficent funds.".format(user))
        else:
            amount = str(amount)
            tx = subprocess.run([core,extra1,extra2,"sendfrom",user,address,amount],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            cleantxid = (tx.stdout.strip()).decode("utf-8")
            txid = str(cleantxid)
            bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="@{0} has successfully withdrew to address: {1} of {2} SPERO\n\n TXID: https://explorer.sperocoin.org/tx/{3}" .format(user,address,amount,txid))

def hello(bot,update):
    user = update.message.from_user.username
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Hello @{0}, how about buying some SPERO at SPERO EXCHANGE?\n https://exchange.sperocoin.org".format(user))

def rain(bot,update):
  bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Stake for a rainy day!")

def price(bot,update):
    speroCapJson = requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/sperocoin').json()
    mk_cap = speroCapJson ['market_data']['market_cap']['brl']
    pricebrl = speroCapJson ['market_data']['current_price']['brl']
    priceusd = speroCapJson ['market_data']['current_price']['usd']
    pricebtc = speroCapJson ['market_data']['current_price']['btc']
    priceeth = speroCapJson ['market_data']['current_price']['eth']
    update.message.reply_text(" Price: \n Cotação/Price: Coingecko \n SPERO Market Cap: R$:{:.2f}".format(mk_cap)+
"\n Price(BRL):  R${:.3f}".format(pricebrl) + "\n Price(USD):  ${:.3f}".format(priceusd) + "\n Price(BTC):  {:.8f}".format(pricebtc) + "\n Price(ETH):  {:.8f}".format(priceeth))


from telegram.ext import CommandHandler

commands_handler = CommandHandler('commands', commands)
dispatcher.add_handler(commands_handler)

rain_handler = CommandHandler('rain', rain)
dispatcher.add_handler(rain_handler)

hi_handler = CommandHandler('hello', hello)
dispatcher.add_handler(hi_handler)

withdraw_handler = CommandHandler('drawout', drawout)
dispatcher.add_handler(withdraw_handler)

deposit_handler = CommandHandler('recharge', recharge)
dispatcher.add_handler(deposit_handler)

tip_handler = CommandHandler('pay', pay)
dispatcher.add_handler(tip_handler)

balance_handler = CommandHandler('funds', funds)
dispatcher.add_handler(balance_handler)

help_handler = CommandHandler('help', help)
dispatcher.add_handler(help_handler)

price_handler = CommandHandler('price', price)
dispatcher.add_handler(price_handler)

updater.start_polling()
```

For the execution of the code, I ran it on a docker:

```
RUN apt update && apt install python3 python3-pip -y
RUN pip3 install beautifulsoup4 \
  && pip3 install requests \
  && pip3 install python-telegram-bot --upgrade
```

Comment: Did the end of the error message get cut off? It's missing the problem string.

Comment: Can you print what was the offending string? Good way to start debugging these kinds of problems, though one can surmise that `clean` is not a string that can be converted to a float. Perhaps it has a currency type like `$` in front of it? Show us!

Comment: It is ending just like that ...
I believe it is, because in this role she would pull the user's balance into that wallet. Which usually comes in the format x.xxxxxxxx (08 decimal places)

Answer (score 0):

This error usually prints what value was not converted:

```
>>> float('blah')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: blah
>>>
```

You have conveniently missed that from your question. Please, take a look at the error message and try to include it completely, or, better yet, figure out yourself, why that value was not successfully converted to `float`.

My suspicion is that the value of `clean` is `''` -- empty string. Which does not look as a float.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was humanly mine ...
The portfolio service had not started with the definition of account activation.
This was not filtering the balance per user.

"enableaccounts=1"